# create iframe of just one div with a class not an id on an external page

Tags: iframe, embed

I need to create an iframe on one div and its content from http://www.mycharitywater.org/cycling-c2b

the div is

```
<div class="dash "></div>
```

and its a charity site who offer no embedable progress bars.

I have tried using possitions on css iframes, with non scrollable, works great except they must use a %age hight somewhere as it doesnt work on all resolutios... Fair enough...

Any ideas would be great as I need to get this out tonight

thanks

Comment: The page I am working on is http://cyclingc2b.org/#!charities.html

Comment: an alternative solution will be for me to make the whole iframe link to the donation page